# Слитно или раздельно: (не)составлениe, (не)соблюдение?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

"Причина (не)составления акта" и "(не)соблюдение порядка оформления"

Слитно или раздельно, и в каких случаях?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Подскажите пожалуйста как пишется "перечень (не)составленных актов", тоже слитно?

Comment: Алла, лучше задайте отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

**Приставка НЕ пишется слитно:** причина несоставления акта,  несоблюдение порядка оформления.

В данном случае нет отрицания,  существительные имеют утвердительное значение: отсутствие составления или соблюдения.

**Примеры:**

Могут лишить статуса даже за неосторожные высказывания и **несоблюдение** деловой лексики. [Александра Маринина. Ангелы на льду не выживают. Т. 1 (2014)]

В первую очередь хотим отметить, что **несоставление** счета-фактуры не нужно рассматривать как отсутствие обязанности продавца начислить НДС.

**Несоставление** протокола по 61 статье прежде всего нарушает права арестованного. [А. Ф. Кони].